# Sessionless ASP.NET on Azure

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure, session-state, appfabric

We have a webform app that is ready for production. We found that SQL and Azure training kit's session state providers are not recommended for production code on Azure. We had no luck with `TableStorageSessionProvider` so far. Unfortunately, our client is not willing to pay for AppFabric Cache. Unless I'm misinformed I see no way to use AppFabric.

We do not use the session ourselves (removed all references to it), would you recommend disabling it or simply using the default provider?

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have no need for session, then it would be best to disable it. Default provider for session state is in memory of a single IIS server and you will likely have 2+ deployed in production. First it takes resources to keep it around, second it leaves an opening for someone in the future to accidentally use it during development w/o realizing overall implications.

HTH

Comment: Is there any Azure-specific side-effects?

Comment: Azure instances are like any other IIS servers.  In memory session state is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Azure instances are not like any other IIS servers. In memory session data is ***NOT*** shared across multiple instances.

If you do not need session state, disable it. If you do, I would recommend checking out AppFabric Cache. We use the AppFabric Session state provider and it works great. If you're interested, this link will help get you started...

http://appfabricdemos.codeplex.com/releases/view/65427

Comment: uhm, In Memory session data is not shared across regular IIS servers either. Questioner clearly stated that AppFabric Cache is not being considered as the client is not willing to pay for it.